# facial rig geometry overlapping

Tags: rigging, bones, faces, geometry

so this basic mouth rig i made was only made so i could make mouth expressions and save them as separate models. but when i made this model, some geometry was overlapping and it stayed that way no matter how much i moved the bones on the mouth. how can i fix this?

Blend file : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1P-QMY0RuMjOokCFjOIL7GTMlD1jFxsBA?usp=sharing

(if textures are needed then let me know)

[image: in object mode]
[image: in edit mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i just realized this is a stupid question. the answer is to just do a better weight painting job